# Use single database for multiuser in Android app?

Tags: android, database

I am developing a app and want to see offline data if Internet is not available . And this app can use multiple user like as after logout one user then another user can login and can see own data So how we can make database to accessible for among user

Comment: Create a table in sqlite database and insert users data, then at the time of login verfiy the user from the database. If the user exist in the database then allow the him the access otherwise show that he/she cannot log in.

Answer (score 0):

Use a discrimator column in your database table design to mark owner ship of every record.

Then you can impl. your data access methods so that they only query records for active user.

It's a design issue not a developing problem ;)